# InitializationError for AndroidJunit4

Tags: android, junit4

I have a single, simple unit test in my Android app module:

```
/src/test/java/org.acme.test/SimpleTest.java
```

When I run:

```
./gradlew clean testDebug --tests='*.SimpleTest'
```

I get this exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: Custom runner class AndroidJUnit4 should have a public constructor with signature AndroidJUnit4(Class testClass)
```

Why does it think 'AndroidJUnit4' is a custom runner class, when it's a final class?

Comment: Why do you keep tests annotated with AndroidJUnit4 in `src/test/` directory? Shouldn't it be in `src/androidTest` directory?

Answer (score 2):

You might have the test class in test directory instead of androidTest.